# is there a practical and simple guide to install symfony on a localhost?

Tags: symfony, frameworks, installation

I'm supposed to edit an existing web application built using symfony framework. so now I have to learn to use symfony framework. but I'm having trouble installing the framework. the download button in symfony.com/download/ seems to be broken. when I click it, it doesn't download anything. it's not because javascript is turned off or anything like it because I can still download other things.

I ended up downloading the file from softpedia and I'm not sure if it's the right file because the contents are different from the tutorial video I found on youtube.

can someone point me to the correct (and working) installation file?

P.S.:
1. I have never used nor installed any php framework. I've only developed websites using flat php and wordpress
2. I don't have access to command prompt because my office admin isn't allowed to give a staff an administrator privileges

thank you

Answer (score 2):

## Direct download of the Symfony2 framework

If you haven't access to the command prompt you could directly download the **Symfony 2.7** package from: http://get.symfony.com/Symfony_Standard_Vendors_2.7.0.zip

In this case the best way to move the first steps with Symfony is to use an IDE (like PhpStorm or [Netbeans](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40565/php-symfony2-framework)).

## Using the command prompt

However, the best way to install and configure a Symfony2 project is described in the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/download) as follows:

```
$ sudo curl -LsS http://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony
$ sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

Then you could use the Symfony binary to build the right scaffolding:

```
$ symfony new my_project
```

Comment: since everyone says that command prompt is the way to go, I've persuaded my office admin to give me access to command prompt. but when I try the commands, it says that 'sudo', 'curl', 'php' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 


when 'sudo' gave an error, I tried omitting it and when 'curl' gave an error, I tried running the command from the symfony documentation book ($ php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony ) but it also gives the same error. what do I do?

Comment: I think this problem is caused by the incorrect command prompt configuration made by the *devop* (office admin). So, the best way to solve this problem is to refer to the machine configuration.
BTW, this is not the scope of your original question, IMHO.